# how to select all parent <li> in nested list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've generated a tree for categories and its subcategories. The depth of tree may go to **n**.
The html code generated is:

```
<ol>
    <li>Category1</li>
    <li>
        Category2
        <ol>
            <li>SubCat21</li>
            <li>SubCat22</li>
            <li class='current-cat'>
                SubCat23
                <ol>
                    <li>SubSubCat231</li>
                    <li>SubSubCat232</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        Category3
        <ol>
            <li>SubCat31</li>
            <li>SubCat32</li>
            <li>
                SubCat33
                <ol>
                    <li>SubSubCat331</li>
                    <li>SubSubCat332</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

As you can see above, the `<li>` having `class='current-cat'` is my current category page. Now using `CSS` I'd shown its child `<ol>` as:

```
ol li>ol{display:none;}
ol li.current-cat>ol{display:block;}
```

But if my current category goes in depth then I'm unable to view the current category as well as its sub-categories.
So I need a way out to make the parent `<li>`s to show child `<ol>` having `<li>` with `class='current-cat'`.

I'd tried it with `jquery` but have not got any success.

[JSFiddle for above tree structure](http://jsfiddle.net/faisal6621/Vv8rZ/)

Comment: I have feeling that accepted answer is so overcomplicated, why not just use `parents()`? Move `current-cat` class around to play with it - http://jsbin.com/aRupiBaf/2/edit

Comment: @WojciechBednarski: post it as your answer. I've questions on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [.ParentsUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/parentsuntil/) you can select your elements

```
$('li#child').ParentsUntil('ol#root', 'li');
```

**Edit:**

In JS:

```
$('ol#root li.current-cat').each(function (index) {
    debugger;
    $(this).parentsUntil('dt', 'ol').css({
        display: 'block'
    });
});
```

or can use this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faisal6621/CGte2/3/)

Comment: what is `li#child` and `ol#root`?

Comment: what should my html tree supposed to be generated?

Comment: Just a second i am updating

Comment: yes, but the problem is, I cannot add `id='root'` to the top `<ol>` because it is generated through a recursive function. But I think I can replace `'ol#root'` to something its top parent.

Comment: thanks for your help. http://jsfiddle.net/faisal6621/CGte2/3/ it works as I want to be

Comment: See the answer [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Antindexer/CGte2/2/) also. It includes for child also. You can give ol#root some contianer name for li#child you can use li.your_class name

Answer (score 1):

I have feeling that accepted answer is so overcomplicated, why not just use [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)?

JS:

```
$('.current-cat').parents('ol').addClass('current');
```

CSS:

```
.current {
  display: block;
}
```

Move `current-cat` class around to play with it - [**example**](http://jsbin.com/aRupiBaf/2/edit)